# Using glGetTexImage() to aquire OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

Im trying to make an OpenCV Mat() using output from OpenGL's glGetTexImage(). The texture I am trying to get information from was made using the call;

```
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8UI, iWidth, iHeight, 0, GL_RGBA_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pImageData);
```

and so I've tried to do this using;

```
    unsigned char* texture_bytes = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*texture_width*texture_height * 3);

    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_bytes);

    Matrix = Mat(texture_height, texture_width, CV_8UC3, texture_bytes);
```

What I am wondering is If anyone knows what I should set the format and type of glGetTexImage() to in order for this to work. Also, what should i set the type of the Mat() to?

You can assume that the context is set correctly, and that the texture that is input is correct. I have verified this by displaying the texture on screen using OpenGL. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your current attempt? Are you not getting any data at all? Or data that looks incorrect? Try calling `glGetError()` just in case, even though the parameters look valid to me.

Comment: My problem arises when I try to get the texture_bytes data out of the given texture. The texture_bytes returns blank (as in "ffffffffffffffffff"). So yes, I am not getting any data at all. I am positive that the data is there, as the texture renders and displays fine in OpenGL, but it will only give me a gray screen in OpenCV. I hope this clarifies the question a bit :)

Comment: Correction, the only data I seem to get from the texture_data is "ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ".

Answer (score 0):

I have been faced with the problem of getting data from OpenGL to OpenCV recently. I didn't use `glGetTexImage` though.

What I did was an offscreen render in a framebuffer with a texture initialized like this:

```
GLuint texture;
if (glIsTexture(texture)) {
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
}
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Then after my draw calls, I get the data using `glReadPixels`:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

cv::Mat texture = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_32FC3);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_BGR, GL_FLOAT, texture.data);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hmmm i was really hoping to not have to go through framebuffers as I am only using OpenGL as a port to OpenCV, but maybe i'll give your version a try if nothing else surfaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch in the *format* parameter used for the `glGetTexImage()` call and the internal format of the texture:

```
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8UI, iWidth, iHeight, 0, GL_RGBA_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pImageData);
...
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_bytes);
```

For an integer texture, which you have in this case, you need to use a *format* parameter to `glGetTexImage()` that works for integer textures. In your example, that would be:

```
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGR_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_bytes);
```

It is always a good idea to call `glGetError()` if you have any kind of problem getting the desired OpenGL behavior. In this case, you would have gotten a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error, based on this error condition in the spec:

> format is one of the integer formats in table 8.3 and the internal format of the texture image is not integer, or format is not one of the integer formats in table 8.3 and the internal format is integer.